# CloudFormation - Start a java backend

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In our template, we setup java, build our application and try to run it.

Everything works as expected, but running the app just won't work. I seems like AWS is waiting for the command to finish but never gets a response (because our Spring Boot Rest Backend would need to terminate for the command to return). I know we did some things in the template that we shouldn't, **but how can we run out app from that template, so that AWS accepts the status as healthy (and therefore doesn't rollback)?** Focus on the commands in the init section. That's where stuff is happening.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "AWS playground",
    "Parameters": {
        "KeyName": {
            "Description": "Key Pair name",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
            "Default": "xyz"
        }
    },
    "Mappings": {
        "EC2RegionMap": {
            "ap-northeast-1": {"AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit": "ami-cbf90ecb"},
            "ap-southeast-1": {"AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit": "ami-68d8e93a"},
            "ap-southeast-2": {"AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit": "ami-fd9cecc7"},
            "eu-central-1": {"AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit": "ami-a8221fb5"},
            "eu-west-1": {"AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit": "ami-a10897d6"},
            "sa-east-1": {"AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit": "ami-b52890a8"},
            "us-east-1": {"AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit": "ami-1ecae776"},
            "us-west-1": {"AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit": "ami-d114f295"},
            "us-west-2": {"AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit": "ami-e7527ed7"}
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "VPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/16",
                "EnableDnsHostnames": "true"
            }
        },
        "InternetGateway": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
            "Properties": {}
        },
        "VPCGatewayAttachment": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
                "InternetGatewayId": {"Ref": "InternetGateway"}
            }
        },
        "SubnetA": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
            "Properties": {
                "AvailabilityZone": {"Fn::Select": ["0", {"Fn::GetAZs": ""}]},
                "CidrBlock": "172.31.38.0/24",
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"}
            }
        },
        "SubnetB": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
            "Properties": {
                "AvailabilityZone": {"Fn::Select": ["1", {"Fn::GetAZs": ""}]},
                "CidrBlock": "172.31.37.0/24",
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"}
            }
        },
        "RouteTable": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"}
            }
        },
        "RouteTableAssociationA": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
            "Properties": {
                "SubnetId": {"Ref": "SubnetA"},
                "RouteTableId": {"Ref": "RouteTable"}
            }
        },
        "RouteTableAssociationB": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
            "Properties": {
                "SubnetId": {"Ref": "SubnetB"},
                "RouteTableId": {"Ref": "RouteTable"}
            }
        },
        "RoutePublicNATToInternet": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {"Ref": "RouteTable"},
                "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "GatewayId": {"Ref": "InternetGateway"}
            },
            "DependsOn": "VPCGatewayAttachment"
        },
        "NetworkAcl": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"}
            }
        },
        "SubnetNetworkAclAssociationA": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation",
            "Properties": {
                "SubnetId": {"Ref": "SubnetA"},
                "NetworkAclId": {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"}
            }
        },
        "SubnetNetworkAclAssociationB": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation",
            "Properties": {
                "SubnetId": {"Ref": "SubnetB"},
                "NetworkAclId": {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"}
            }
        },
        "NetworkAclEntryIngress": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry",
            "Properties": {
                "NetworkAclId": {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"},
                "RuleNumber": "100",
                "Protocol": "-1",
                "RuleAction": "allow",
                "Egress": "false",
                "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
        },
        "NetworkAclEntryEgress": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry",
            "Properties": {
                "NetworkAclId": {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"},
                "RuleNumber": "100",
                "Protocol": "-1",
                "RuleAction": "allow",
                "Egress": "true",
                "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
        },
        "LoadBalancer": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
                "Subnets": [{"Ref": "SubnetA"}, {"Ref": "SubnetB"}],
                "LoadBalancerName": "school-elb",
                "Listeners": [{
                    "InstancePort": "80",
                    "InstanceProtocol": "HTTP",
                    "LoadBalancerPort": "80",
                    "Protocol": "HTTP"
                }],
                "HealthCheck": {
                    "HealthyThreshold": "2",
                    "Interval": "5",
                    "Target": "TCP:80",
                    "Timeout": "3",
                    "UnhealthyThreshold": "2"
                },
                "SecurityGroups": [{"Ref": "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup"}],
                "Scheme": "internet-facing"
            },
            "DependsOn": "VPCGatewayAttachment"
        },
        "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "school-elb-sg",
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "ToPort": "80"
                }]
            }
        },
        "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "school-sg",
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "FromPort": "22",
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "ToPort": "22"
                }, {
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "ToPort": "80",
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "SourceSecurityGroupId": {"Ref": "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup"}
                }]
            }
        },
        "LaunchConfiguration": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                  "config": {
                    "packages": {
                      "yum": {
                        "java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel": []
                      }
                    },
                    "sources": {
                      "/opt": "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip",
                      "/home/ec2-user": "https://github.com/yandypiedra/AWS_Cloud_Formation/archive/master.zip"
                    },
                    "files": {
                      "/tmp/depend_config": {
                        "content": {
                          "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                              "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
                              "chmod -R 755 gradle-3.4.1/\n",
                              "echo \"PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle-3.4.1/bin\" >> /etc/environment\n",
                              "yum install -y java-1.8.0\n"
                            ]
                          ]
                        },
                        "mode": "000500",
                        "owner": "root",
                        "group": "root"
                      },
                      "/tmp/app_config": {
                        "content": {
                          "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                              "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
                              "chmod -R 777 AWS_Cloud_Formation-master/\n",
                              "/opt/gradle-3.4.1/bin/gradle build -p /home/ec2-user/AWS_Cloud_Formation-master/src/Hi/\n"
                            ]
                          ]
                        },
                        "mode": "000500",
                        "owner": "root",
                        "group": "root"
                      },
                                            "/tmp/launch_server": {
                                                "content": {
                          "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                              "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
                              "chmod -R 777 AWS_Cloud_Formation-master/\n",
                              "java -jar AWS_Cloud_Formation-master/src/Hi/build/libs/hi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\n"
                            ]
                          ]
                        },
                        "mode": "000500",
                        "owner": "root",
                        "group": "root"
                                            }
                    },
                    "commands": {
                      "01_config": {
                        "command": "/tmp/depend_config",
                        "cwd": "/opt"
                      },
                      "02_config": {
                        "command": "yum remove -y java-1.7.0-openjdk"
                      },
                      "03_config": {
                        "command": "/tmp/app_config",
                        "cwd": "/home/ec2-user"
                      },
                      "04_config": {
                        "command": "/tmp/launch_server",
                        "cwd": "/home/ec2-user"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
            },
            "Properties": {
                "EbsOptimized": false,
                "ImageId": {"Fn::FindInMap": ["EC2RegionMap", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, "AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit"]},
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "SecurityGroups": [{"Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"}],
                "KeyName": {"Ref": "KeyName"},
                "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true,
                "UserData": {"Fn::Base64": {"Fn::Join": ["", [
                    "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
                    "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
                    "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ", {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, " --resource LaunchConfiguration --region ", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, "\n",
                    "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ", {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, " --resource AutoScalingGroup --region ", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, "\n"
                ]]}}
            }
        },
        "AutoScalingGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "LoadBalancerNames": [{"Ref": "LoadBalancer"}],
                "LaunchConfigurationName": {"Ref": "LaunchConfiguration"},
                "MinSize": "1",
                "MaxSize": "1",
                "DesiredCapacity": "1",
                "VPCZoneIdentifier": [{"Ref": "SubnetA"}, {"Ref": "SubnetB"}]
            },
            "CreationPolicy": {
                "ResourceSignal": {
                    "Timeout": "PT15M"
                }
            },
            "DependsOn": "VPCGatewayAttachment"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it as a [service/deamon](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service)? Or maybe use a [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

Comment: `nohup` was the solution!